# ConstraintLayout breaking when switching from Portrait to Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Right now I have two different layout files, one for Large and one for large-land.  Both are using constraint layouts.  However whenever the tablet switches from portrait to landscape mode, the landscape mode layout displays correctly.  But after switching back to portrait and back to landscape mode, the landscape layout no longer displays correctly.  The right side of the layout seems to have extended past the actual screen.

To simplify,
Portrait -> Landscape: Landscape displays correctly
Portrait -> Landscape -> Portrait -> Landscape: Landscape layout breaks and extends past the screen for some reason.

Any idea why this may be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a simple pair of XML's that display the problem?